# DatePickerSelectedDateChanged event occurs twice when manually enter date

Tags: wpf, events, datepicker

I have a DatePicker managing SelectedDateChanged event:

```
<DatePicker Name="myDatePicker" SelectedDateChanged="myDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" />
```

If I choose a date with the calendar, SelectedDateChanged event is fired once. If I change date manually, SelectedDateChanged event is fired twice.

I found other people speaking about the same problem and resolving it by setting a flag when event is first fired, and test the flag value.

**I would like to find a different approach to solve my issue, without using a flag.**

Comment: If You repeat changing the date manually, does the event ALWAYS occurr twice or only the first time with manual changing ?

Comment: @icbytes If I repeat changing the date manually, the event always occurs twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time it fires for DatePicker SelectedDate and second time for Calendar SelectedDate... So it's not error, it's strange logic.

Comment: Ok, so another question: how could I stop the Calendar SelectedDateChanged event to occur then?

Comment: I suppose that easiest way will be create custom DatePicker. As I see in sources, it will be enough to override OnApplyTemplate and create PART_Popup by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I wanted.
When form is loaded, I added GotFocus and LostFocus events to the DatePicker TextBox (using Template.FindName method). I also added CalendarOpened and CalendarClosed event on the DatePicker.
It's not very elegant and if you think there is a better way, fell free to comment, I am a beginner in WPF...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private TextBox txtDtPicker;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDtPicker = (TextBox)myDatePicker.Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", myDatePicker);

        myDatePicker.CalendarOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(myDatePicker_CalendarOpened);
        myDatePicker.CalendarClosed += new RoutedEventHandler(myDatePicker_CalendarClosed);

        txtDtPicker.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(txtDtPicker_GotFocus);
        txtDtPicker.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(txtDtPicker_LostFocus);
    }

    private void txtDtPicker_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myDatePicker.SelectedDateChanged += new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(myDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged);
    }

    private void txtDtPicker_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myDatePicker.SelectedDateChanged -= new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(myDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged);
    }

    private void myDatePicker_CalendarOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myDatePicker.SelectedDateChanged += new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(myDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged);
    }

    private void myDatePicker_CalendarClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myDatePicker.SelectedDateChanged -= new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(myDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged);

        // When calendar is closed after a date selection, unfocus and focus again txtDtPicker. If not done, SelectedDateChanged event will not fire if date is changed manually just after changed was done with calendar
        myDatePicker.Focus();
        txtDtPicker.Focus();
    }

    int iNbTimesEventOccurs = 0;

    private void myDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Remove event to prevent it to happen twice
        myDatePicker.SelectedDateChanged -= new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(myDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged);

        // Just to control event is not fired several times
        iNbTimesEventOccurs++;
        textBlock1.Text = "Nb times event occurs: " + iNbTimesEventOccurs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... Maybe will be easier to keep DatePicker value and check, if it really was changed on SelectedDateChanged event?

Comment: Yep, I agree with you! That's what I'm gonna do